# postgresql jpa hibernate exception: Found: date, expected: timestamp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have some probles with JPA **@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)** annotation, during application demployment.
So I created spring data + postgres 9.5 + hibernate 4.3.10 app and setted *hbm2ddl.auto* to '*validate*'.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate
```

Here is Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locomotive")
public class LocomotiveEntity {

    private Long locomotiveId;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private java.util.Date constructionYear;
...
```

Also I created *locomotive* table using this script:

```
CREATE TABLE "locomotive"
(
    "locomotiveId"  bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    "status" integer NOT NULL,
    "constructionYear" DATE NOT NULL
);
```

But I see exception during demployment:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong 
column type in public.constructionYear for column constructionYear.
 Found: date, expected: timestamp
```

So I have 'DATE' type column in my db, and 'DATE' java type. What I did wrong?

Comment: If you look at the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), you see that the  `date` type does not include the time of day. You have to use at least `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` like this:

```
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private Date constructionYear;
```